# Prove that $\frac{\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\dots+\frac{1}{200}}{\frac{1}{10*11}+\frac{1}{11*12}+\dots+\frac{1}{19*20}}>19$

Tags: inequality, summation, fractions, harmonic-numbers, telescopic-series

Prove that $$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{12}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{200}}{\dfrac{1}{10\cdot11}+\dfrac{1}{11\cdot12}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{19\cdot20}}>19$$

**My attempt**:The denominator is $\frac{1}{20}$ using telescopic series.

$\frac{1}{10*11}+\frac{1}{11*12}+\dots+\frac{1}{19*20}=\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{12}+\dots-\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{20}$

I think we could Prove that the top part of fraction is bigger than $1$ but I don't know how.

Comment: The numerator is $> \frac{190}{200}$.

Comment: Oh yes I didn't notice you mean I should take all fractions $\frac{1}{200}$?

Comment: Taking the approximation for the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) the numerator is about $\log 200 - \log 10 \approx 2.9957$ so the whole fraction is almost $60$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calculation for the denominator (telescopic sum and not series) was the hard part, since 
\begin{align}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{12}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{200}}{\dfrac{1}{20}}&>\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{200}+\dfrac{1}{200}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{200}}{\dfrac{1}{20}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{200-10}{200}}{\dfrac1{20}}=\frac{\dfrac{19}{20}}{\dfrac1{20}}=19\end{align}